# Is there an emulator for Moto 3G?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, motorola, motorola-droid

I'm developing an app using Android Studio, which I would like to test on Moto 3G.  According to beta testers, something funny is going on with the app on this particular phone: my custom buttons are invisible yet still functional.

Is there a Moto 3G emulator for Android Studio? Or another that would be equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like this might be a layout related issue, you could probably start by creating an Android Virtual Device (AVD) that mimics the specs of the Moto 3G and see if you can reproduce.

Looking at the [specs for the Moto 3G](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_(3rd_gen)-7247.php)

- Display: 720 x 1280 (294 ppi density)
- OS: Android 5.1.1 (API 22) upgradable to Android 6.0 (API 23)

So you could [create an AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) that uses API 22 or API 23 with a 720 x 1280 display.

I would encourage you to ask clarifying questions from your testers.  For example, ask for screenshots of the bug.  Can they attach logcat logs? Were they in portrait or landscape mode when the issue occurred?  Etc.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestion! Unfortunately, even after creating an AVD with exactly the same specifications, including screen size and resolution, the app continues to work perfectly on all emulators. In other words, I can't recreate the invisible buttons on the actual Moto 3G. Very very strange. Can you think of any reason why buttons would be invisble, but still function (i.e., can be clicked)? I just don't get what's going on.